# Javascript extract numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, substring, slice

I want to **extract numbers from a string** in javascript like following :

**if  the string = 'make1to6' i would like to extract the numeric character before and after the 'to' substring in the entire string. i.e. 1 and 6 are to be extracted**

The length of the string is not fixed and can be a max of 10 characters in length.The number can be of max two digits on either side of 'to' in the string.

**Possible string values :**

- sure1to3
- ic3to9ltd
- anna1to6
- joy1to4val
- make6to12
- ext12to36

thinking of something like :

```
function beforeTo(string) {
    return numeric_value_before_'to'_in_the_string;
}

function afterTo(string) {
    eturn numeric_value_after_'to'_in_the_string;
}
```

i will be using these returned values for some calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example function that will return an array representing the two numbers, or `null` if there wasn't a match:

```
function extractNumbers(str) {
    var m = /(\d+)to(\d+)/.exec(str);
    return m ? [+m[1], +m[2]] : null;
}
```

You can adapt that regular expression to suit your needs, say by making it case-insensitive: `/(\d+)to(\d+)/i.exec(str)`.

Comment: @Sandy505: Well, you recognize the regular expression, right? `/(\d+)to(\d+)/`. We'll start with that. `\d` means "any digit, from 0 to 9." `\d+` means "at least one digit." `to` just matches the word "to." `.exec` executes the expression on the string, and turns it into an array of matches. So `m[1]` is the first group of digits, and `m[2]` is the second group of digits... we return those in an array if it matched. That's it. You can now access the first number as `myArray[0]` and the second as `myArray[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to find it:

```
var str = "sure1to3";
var matches = str.match(/(\d+)to(\d+)/);
if (matches) {
    // matches[1] = digits of first number
    // matches[2] = digits of second number
}
```